# Method to generate 2D arrays with specified autocorrelation?

Tags: autocorrelation, stochastic-processes, matrix, spatial, random-generation

Suppose I have a specified value of autocorrelation (say 0.9) at lag 1. Is there a way to generate a random 2D (NxN) array which will have this particular autocorrelation value at the same lag?